# How to create an 802.11n wireless network between laptops

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, 802.11n, ad-hoc-network

I have an ASUS USB-N13 wireless adapter and three laptops in a home. I've tried multiple times to create an ad-hoc network following the 802.11n standard, but failed each time. The laptops have Intel WiFi Link 5100 802.11a/b/g/n wireless adapters.

I tried to create a network with WPA2 personal encryption. That failed (couldn't connect). With WEP encryption, it connected, but with the 802.11g standard, not 802.11n.

How can I create an 802.11n-based network? Do I definitely need a router to use the 802.11n standard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wireless network structure that you describe is called ad-hoc, which is the mode for wireless devices to directly communicate with each other. The alternative when using a router is called infrastructure mode.

For most manufacturers of wireless adapters, 802.11n is only possible in infrastructure mode, which requires a router. Without a router, you won't get beyond 802.11g. You should also get a router that allows setting an option for "N only", so as to force all laptops to this mode.

For example, this is what Netgear [says](http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1069/kw/ad-hoc%20mode/r_id/100109):

> IEEE wireless standards are used for
>   all NETGEAR wireless products.
>   Standards IEEE 802.11b and IEEE
>   802.11g specify that when in Ad-Hoc mode, wireless products only need to
>   support 11 Mbps. These IEEE standards
>   apply to "b", "g" and "Super G"
>   products.
>
> **To get top performance, use Infrastructure mode instead.**

And this is what D-Link [says](http://www.dlink.com/support/faq/default.aspx?prod_id=1482&question=802.11g%2Bad%2Bhoc):

> **Q:** Why can´t I get the advertised speed and performance when in Ad-Hoc
>   mode?
>   **A:** D-Link wireless products follow the IEEE 802.11 standards. The 802.11b
>   and 802.11g standards specify that
>   Ad-Hoc mode only needs to support up
>   to 11Mbps. **For best results, use an
>   access point or wireless router and
>   set your adapters to Infrastructure
>   (station) mode.**

Answer (score 0):

One problem at emerges a lot during N networking is G support. If you do not require G support try turning it off in the router. It has been known to distabalize the whole network.

Comment: we don't use router just 3 laptop ( for ex we play call of duty 4 with laptops after for a while game stacks )